# Improper center() alignment of Python strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, format, alignment

I'm working on a projects that shows basic user details.

Here's the respective code that I'm having problem with.

```
@wrap
def show(self, *ids):
    for id in ids:
        try:
            user = self.api.get_user(id)
            print(user.name.center(80, '~'))
            print('%d Followers    %d Following'.center(80, '~') %
                    (user.followers_count, user.friends_count))
        except Exception:
            print('Error')
        finally:
            print()
```

The code shows both the lines with the max-width of 80 chars.
At this point it should only print maximum of 80 chars on each line.
But I'm getting this output :

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Twitter~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~58312564 Followers    1 Following~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The first line is seems perfect but the second line is really not looking at the center.

> I read the docs and I also tried using .format() inside the print statement but I'm getting the same problem.

How can I print both the line contents at the center?
(One character difference is considerable)

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does This work for you?

```py
followers_count= 5831256
friends_count = 1
var = f" {followers_count} Followers  {friends_count} Following "
print(f"{' Twitter ':~^80}")
print(f"{var:~^80}")
```

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Twitter ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 5831256 Followers  1 Following ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Adapt it to your method definition.
Note: var is unnecessary

Comment: It worked! I simply printed the var content inside the print() and the added a .center(80). Good work !